# Show attribute with type Media Image on category listing

Tags: attributes, product-images, media

I'm trying to show a link to the `Base Image` of a product. This attribute is a Media Image type and Magento doesn't hydrate this attribute on the category listing. I was able to make it available by manually changing the `used_in_product_listing` column to `1`.

Will this affect anything in Magento in an adverse way? Why is this field hidden on the attribute form when `Media Image` is selected?

Comment: This will give you some more info: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/media-attribute-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @MagePsycho I already did those. I'm wondering if there's a reason behind why it has to be changed manually. I'm also wondering why Magento doesn't allow it to be changed in Magento Admin.

Answer (score 1):

This should not affect anything. By setting `used_in_product_listing` to 'yes' will only add a column to catalog_product_flat_[X] table.

When you use the workaround it will only add ONE field.

Eg.

```
`test_mediaimage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'test_mediaimage',
```

However the default media type add 2 field to your flat table.

Eg.

```
`thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail',
`thumbnail_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail_label',

`small_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'small_image',
`small_image_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'small_image_label',

`thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail',
`thumbnail_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'thumbnail_label',
```

If you need to also include the label text on your category page, you could manually create a `test_mediaimage_label` and then reindex